# The operation couldn't be completed (IDEStackFrame Error 0.)

Tags: ios, xcode6

I was attempting to use the 3-D view hierarchy viewer in the debugger, by selecting Capture View Hierarchy in the View Debugging Debug menu option. I've used it before with success. This time, though, I get the error:

```
The operation couldn't be completed (IDEStackFrame Error 0.)
```

Any idea what this means? Is there something I can do differently for a retry?

I'm using the iPhone 5 (32 bit) simulator in portrait mode running Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this error when I tried to debug the view hierarchy while I was viewing code with the version editor. When I switched xcode to the standard editor, debug view hierarchy started working again.

Comment: Thanks. For what it's worth, I also submitted a bug report (20224068) to Apple about this. Seems like it should be an easy fix.

Comment: Got an update from Apple who now have determined this is a duplicate of bug report (20213046).